# How to know whether a file is encrypted by AES 256 in Mac using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, aes

Need to know whether a file is encrypted by AES 256 in Mac, but using objective c code.

Comment: I don't think there is such thing as ASE encryption. Did you mean [AES (Advanced Encryption Standard)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, in general. Encrypted data is indistinguishable from random data.

If you're dealing with a specific application, it may put a particular header or footer on the data that you can use to identify it. But a general "is this data that has been encrypted with AES-256" function is impossible.